# How do I send an email on Android by executing a process

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

I am working on adding calls to the Android shell from within the app. I have been able to call shell scripts or basic shell commands very well, but now I am trying to send an email (mostly to know if I can) and am running into a strange error:

```
11-06 16:14:43.449: D/AndroidRuntime(28655): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
11-06 16:14:43.449: D/AndroidRuntime(28655): CheckJNI is OFF
11-06 16:14:43.629: D/AndroidRuntime(28655): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-06 16:14:43.639: D/AndroidRuntime(28655): Shutting down VM
11-06 16:14:43.639: I/ActivityManager(204): START {act=android.intent.action.SENDTO typ="text/plain" flg=0x10000000 pkg=Goes (has extras)} from pid 28655
11-06 16:14:43.649: D/dalvikvm(28655): GC_CONCURRENT freed 104K, 81% free 495K/2560K, paused 0ms+1ms
11-06 16:14:43.649: D/dalvikvm(28655): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-06 16:14:43.649: I/AndroidRuntime(28655): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #2' failed
```

The code that is run by my shell is this:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -t "text/plain" --es android.intent.extra.EMAIL "myaddress@example.com" --es android.intent.extra.TEXT "Message Goes here" --es android.intent.extra.SUBJECT "this is the subject"
```

What is going wrong, and how can I fix it? Is there a different tool (other than `am`) that I should be using?

Comment: First this is a silly and officially unsupported way to do things - issuing shell commands from within an app is discouraged, and rather tricky as a review of relevant questions will show.  The shell can't send Intents anyway - the am command fires up a Dalvik vm to do it, so you might as well just send the Intent from your app.  In terms of details, does the command string work if you paste it into an ADB shell?  If so, are you sure you actually issuing this command to a shell process which will parse it, or are you trying to exec am without a shell to assemble its paramaters?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I completely agree that this is silly - but as a developer, I like to pursue interesting ideas. Thanks for suggesting to try it from my remote adb shell. I needed to change the action to `SEND` instead of `SENDTO`. But as you suspected, *this command* does not work on-device. As for how I am running this: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(<insert-code-from-above>)`.

Comment: Android's runtime exec with a single string argument takes only a program name, while Sun Java's takes a string which may include both command and arguments.  To pass arguments to an android process you will need to use one of the other methods, amply documented in numerous questions here.  You might (?) also need to give the full path name of the target executable.

Comment: Incidentally, no shell is involved in your attempt - exec launches the 'am' command directly without a shell, so I removed that from the question.

Comment: I have some other methods in place to pass parameters, so I will test it out in a little bit. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I rolled back the revision to the question, since I am looking for any solution that will work from the Android shell - not necessarily one based on the `am` tool.

Comment: exec() **does not invoke a shell** unless you explicitly specify the shell executable as the program to execute.

Comment: Got it. The current title is a good fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts at this, I have come to believe that you cannot start an Activity from `am` on-device. You can, however, send broadcasts, which can be used to start an Activity. For example, to start the camera app, you can use this:

```
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON
```

Comment: Really?  Your quoted log messages seem to indicate that the intent is being built and sent appropriately, but that 'am' is misinterpreting what intent to send, perhaps because the quoting is being misunderstood.  Try your original code with a single word body and single word subject, and note that it appears to be interpreting the first additional parameter as a package, which means you may or may not need to specify one...

Answer (score 1):

Please try this if you are in adb shell:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:xxx --es sms_body "xxx" --ez exit_on_sent true
input keyevent 66
```

I just tried on my Droid X running Android 4.0(ICS). It will send the SMS and exit. Please let me know if this helps.

Regards,

Comment: This does not help. I found this on a separate post. I want to send an email, not a text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to send an email. run this code in real device because the adb doesn't have any third party permissions

package com.rmn.emailSending;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EmailSendingActivity extends Activity {
    Button send;
    EditText address, subject, emailtext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emailsendbutton);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailaddress);
        subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailsubject);
        emailtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailtext);

        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { address.getText().toString() });
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject.getText().toString());
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,emailtext.getText().toString());
                EmailSendingActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail in"));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: **Actually, this is the proper answer.** Though the permissions issue is not true in most cases, as typical mail clients rely on interactive user confirmation to decide if the email should really be sent. Also, ADB is not even involved in the OP's commandline attempt so the shell or am tool would run as the uid of the invoking app, rather than as the adb shell user.

Comment: *Proper*, yes. *Answer* no. This is the way to send an email using Intent in Java Android, but this is not how to send using `am` in the adb shell.

Comment: @Phil you **are not using** the ADB shell, or any shell at all in your question!!